# Load a .docx and parse it into an array using PHP

Tags: php, arrays, associative-array, phpword

I want a .docx to become an associative PHP array containing element type and element content, something like this:

```
$my_document = array(
    array(
        'type' => 'h1',
        'content' => 'Hello world'
    ),
    array(
        'type' => 'p',
        'content' => 'I am a paragraph'
    )
);
```

I've tried using [PHPWord](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord), but to no success. Using code from the example allows me to load a .docx file, but I can only write it to HTML, PDF or RTF files.

There seems to be no way to just return the contents in some sort of associative array.

**Load .docx and save it as HTML:**

```
$source =  "word.docx";
echo date('H:i:s'), " Reading contents from `{$source}`";

$phpWord = \PhpOffice\PhpWord\IOFactory::load($source);
$writer = new \PhpOffice\PhpWord\Writer\HTML($phpWord);
$writer->save("my_document.html");
```

The above example works, but as said, I end up with an HTML file on the server -- not an array in memory.

---

### Is there a way to use PHPWord or another library to load a .docx file, and return its structure as an associative array?

---

*Other thoughts: I've looked into loading the saved HTML file as a DOMDocument and getting the contents from there, but this seems inefficient.*

Comment: *Is there a way to use PHPWord or another library to load a .docx file, and return its structure as an associative array?*. Yes. I would it would be incredibly annoying and hard though, so is there really a reason to do this?

Comment: I think your "inefficient" solution is actually the best. Get the docx file to HTML as efficiently as possible, and then focus on finding the best HTML parser. There are far, far more options for handling/parsing HTML.

Comment: @Loek I'm building a service where users can import word files in a browser based text editor, so yes :-)

Comment: @Here2Help Thanks, will pursue that path!

Comment: @Rein Then I'd really suggest you would go the DOMDocument/HTML path indeed. Good luck!

Comment: I'm currently creating a PhpWord writer to parse the imported file to an associative array. Will publish on github when stable.